# Why don't my retract menu pop out?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my [current project](https://codepen.io/Hello911/pen/oeaddP?editors=0010) on CodePen.Below is my code. Sorry if it's too long. I tried to make it short by not adding the animation.

The desire effect is when you click the menu icon the first nav bar slides in and the second one with a cross icon slides out. But I don't know where is my second nav bar, it's not appearing.

```js
//This function retracts the menu bar with the menu icon and expand the menu bar with close icon.
function open(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.width = "20%"; 
}
//This thing does the opposite of the above function
function close(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.width = "20%";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.width = "0px"; 
}
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
/*First nav bar of the two. You press the menu icon, this bar slides in and the second nav bar slides out.*/
.openNav{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
}
.openBox{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2);
  position:relative;
  bottom:15px;
}
.open{
  font-size:50px;
  color: #818181;
}
/*Second nav bar with a close button. You press the close button, the bar slides in and the first nav bar slides out.*/
.closeNav{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
}
.closeBox{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2);
  position:relative;
  bottom:15px;
}
.close{
  font-size:50px;
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<div class='openNav' id='openNav'>
  <div class='openBox'>
    <div class='open' onclick='open()'>&#9776</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='closeNav' id='closeNav'>
  <div class='closeBox'>
    <div class='close' onclick='close()'>&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the second nav bar is at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your click handler when you call `open()` it isn't calling *your* function, it is calling [`document.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open), which has the effect of completely clearing the current page. If you put a debug breakpoint in your function, or just use `console.log()` or `alert()` to test it, you'll see that your `open()` isn't run at all.

If you give the function another name the code seems to work:

```js
//This function retracts the menu bar with the menu icon and expand the menu bar with close icon.
function openNav(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.width = "20%"; 
}
//This thing does the opposite of the above function
function closeNav(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.width = "20%";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.width = "0px"; 
}
```

```css
*{ padding:0; margin:0; }
html, body{ height:100%; width:100%; }
/*First nav bar of the two. You press the menu icon, this bar slides in and the second nav bar slides out.*/
.openNav{ height:100%; width:20%; background:#111; }
.openBox{ width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2); position:relative; bottom:15px; }
.open{ font-size:50px; color: #818181; }
/*Second nav bar with a close button. You press the close button, the bar slides in and the first nav bar slides out.*/
.closeNav{ height:100%; width:20%; background:#111; }
.closeBox{ width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2); position:relative; bottom:15px; }
.close{ font-size:50px; color: #818181; }
```

```html
<div class='openNav' id='openNav'>
  <div class='openBox'>
    <div class='open' onclick='openNav()'>&#9776</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='closeNav' id='closeNav'>
  <div class='closeBox'>
    <div class='close' onclick='closeNav()'>&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may also want to call `closeNav()` once immediately on page load to set the correct starting state. (The layout seems a bit weird having both icons at 100% height, but that's not related to the problem you seem to be asking about so I'll ignore that. Note that I didn't change your CSS, I just removed line breaks so it wouldn't take up as much space in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("openNav").addEventListener("click",open);
document.getElementById("closeNav").addEventListener("click",close); 
//This function retracts the menu bar with the menu icon and expand the menu bar with close icon.
function open(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.display = "block"; 
}
//This thing does the opposite of the above function
function close(){
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("closeNav").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
/*First nav bar of the two. You press the menu icon, this bar slides in and the second nav bar slides out.*/
.openNav{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
}
.openBox{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2);
  position:relative;
  bottom:15px;
}
.open{
  font-size:50px;
  color: #818181;
}
/*Second nav bar with a close button. You press the close button, the bar slides in and the first nav bar slides out.*/
.closeNav{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
  display:none;
}
.closeBox{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:calc((100% - 50px)/2);
  position:relative;
  bottom:15px;
}
.close{
  font-size:50px;
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<div class='openNav' id='openNav'>
  <div class='openBox'>
    <div class='open'>&#9776</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='closeNav' id='closeNav'>
  <div class='closeBox'>
    <div class='close'>&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try use addEventListeners instead of onClick attribute. I changed it to display css property since the width thing is not working properly. Probably has something to do with your animation.